# ASP.net Site.master

Tags: html, asp.net

I am having error when trying to run a web page "code blocks are not supported in this context"

I am using this code in site.master

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
            <li>
                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
            </li>
        </ul>`enter code here`
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Whart are you trying to accomplish with the `\`enter code here\`` in line 15? Have you tried without it?

Comment: I pasted your snippet into Visual Studio for testing. It works, no errors. The problem is most likely not in there.

Comment: Yes It is Resolved!

Comment: I just cleaned the solution and its resolved Thanks for your prompt reply...........